# R set column to maximum of current entry and specified value in an elegant way

Tags: r

NOTE: I technically know how to do this, but I feel like there has to be a "nicer" way to do this. If such questions are not allowed here just delete it, but I would really like to improve my `R` style, so any suggestions are welcome.

I have a dataframe `data <- data.frame(foo=rep(c(-1,2),5))`

```
   foo
1   -1
2    2
3   -1
4    2
5   -1
6    2
7   -1
8    2
9   -1
10   2
```

Now I would like to be able to set the entries of `foo` to a certain value (for this example, let's say 1) if the current entry is smaller than that value.
So my desired output would be

```
   foo
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    1
6    2
7    1
8    2
9    1
10   2
```

I feel like there should be something like `data$foo <- max(data$foo,1)` that does the job (but ofc, it "maxes" over the whole column).

Is there an elegant way to do this?

`data$foo <- ifelse(data$foo < 1,1,data$foo)` and `data$foo <- lapply(data$foo,function(x) max(1,x))` just feel somewhat "ugly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max` gives you maximum of the whole column but for your case you need `pmax`(`p`arallel `max`imum) so it gives you maximum of 1 or each number in the vector.

```
data$foo <- pmax(data$foo, 1)
data

#   foo
#1    1
#2    2
#3    1
#4    2
#5    1
#6    2
#7    1
#8    2
#9    1
#10   2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is excactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
data <- data.frame(foo=rep(c(-1,2),5))

val <- 1

data[data$foo < val, ] <- val
```

Let's break this down. `data$foo` takes the column and makes it into a vector. `data$foo < val` checks which elements of this vector are smaller than `val`, creating a new vector of similar lenghts filled with `TRUE` and `FALSE` at the correct positions.

Finally, the entire line `data[data$foo < val, ] <- val` uses that vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` to select the rows (using the `[, ]`) of `data` to which `val` is now used.

Comment: Although I personally think the pmax solution is a little bit more elegant in this special case this solution is more flexible and also seems to be a little faster (approx. 20% in my tests). For an even faster solution use the data.table version data[foo < 1, foo := 1]).